# I need mongodb group pipeline for multiple condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
Document

    [
        {
            type: 1,//credit
            amount: 60
        },
        {
            type: 2,//debit
            amount: 35
        },
        {
            type: 3,//credit
            amount: 25
        },
        {
            type: 4,//debit
            amount: 80
        },
        {
            type: 5,//credit
            amount: 70
        },
    ]

Result

[
    {
        _id: {
            Name: "Credition",
            Type: [1, 3, 5]
        },
        Total_Amount: 155
    },
    {
        _id: {
            Name: "Debition",
            Type: [2, 4]
        },
        Total_Amount: 115
    },
]
```

In my schema, there are millions of logs records in which few are credited logs, few are debited logs.

I want to use MongoDB aggregate pipe and have to group like above for million records at a time

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that first you need to add a new field transaction on the basis of the type of logs, then you can group the logs on the basis of that field.

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/e4kqeKLIuIr

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      transaction: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "$type",
              [
                1,
                3,
                5
              ]
            ]
          },
          then: "Credition",
          else: "Debition"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$transaction",
      Type: {
        $addToSet: "$type"
      },
      Total_Amount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

After this, you can also use $project operator to change the name or structure of the record, if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `$cond` during the grouping stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [ "$type", [1,3,5] ]
          },
          "Credition",
          "Debition"
        ]
      },
      type: {
        $addToSet: "$type"
      },
      amount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        Name: "$_id",
        Type: "$type"
      },
      Total_Amount: "$amount"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MGQPN7VZKpE)